# Unclear wording on comment editing timeout

Tags: bug, comments

So when trying to edit a comment before 5 minutes after posting, you get the error message "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes."

I think that message is is unclear and should be changed to something like "Comments may only be edited *after* 5 minutes" or "Comments may only be edited 5 minutes after posting."

Any objections?

[image: Screenshot of the message.]

Comment: It feels like a slight softening of "Comments are only editable for 5 minutes". If you feel strongly about getting the wording changed then I suspect that https://meta.stackexchange.com/ might be a more appropriate place for this kind of question.

Comment: Should this post be closed due to the fact that I was mistaken about the true meaning of the message?

Answer (score 7):

> I think that message is unclear and should be changed to something like "Comments may only be edited after 5 minutes" or "Comments may only be edited 5 minutes after posting."

In the English language, your suggestion would mean that comments could only be edited,  5 minutes after they were submitted.  Which of course is **not the case**, and in reality, **after 5 minutes have passed you no longer can edit a comment.**

The statement as it is currently written actually is grammatically correct.

Comment: My complete mistake, then. I was under the impression that it was in fact *after* five minutes. I still think the message could be a tad bit more clear, and I like the way @Mokubai put it in his comment on the OP, and I think I'll bring it up on the stack exchange meta that way. Thanks for the clarification!